# Setting up web app on webspere application server

Tags: jsp, websphere

So company gave me this Web App without any documentation, it has a few java classes and a bunch of JSP files, previously, it was running on a tomcat server, and now they want to put it on websphere. Since the person who was working on this left the company, so I am very confused just on how to set it up and make it run.

So far I imported the project and made a websphere application server profile, and try to publish it. But it gives me error as "The deployment descriptor of the module "XXX" cannot be loaded or found", and I am stuck here.

So what's instructions that I should follow? Should I look for any files? Any helps are appreciated!!

Comment: Imported it into where and published it to where? Did the web app come with a WAR or EAR file?

Comment: Imported into Rational developer and I was trying to publish on localhost. The web app didn't come with a WAR or EAR file

Comment: Ok, and the source had no web.xml either? That's "the deployment descriptor" it's complaining about.

Comment: it has web.xml, but I don't think it is doing anything, is that the file I need to implement? Right now it has <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app></web-app>

Comment: When you double-click to open web.xml, does it open in the RAD Deployment Descriptor Editor, or just in a plain text XML editor? In your RAD project facets, do you have Dynamic Web Module selected? Is web.xml in the directory "Web Content/WEB-INF"?

Comment: So it didn't open in the RAD Deployment Descriptor Editor. And I can't find RAD project facets. And yes, web.xml was in the directory "Web Content/WEB-INF", and i was wrong with the web.xml i just gave to you, there is more to it. It has a bunch of <servlet>
     <servlet-name>xxx</servlet-name>
     <jsp-file>/xxx.jsp</jsp-file>  
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xxx</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>